# Can opaque element hide other elements?

Tags: html, css, background, opacity

I've used a technique here with jQuery, HTML and so on. If I select an element its background will be a sliding lines animated gif so if I put another div in front of it and i made the back div 1 pixel wider than the front then it will look like the selection effect on photoshop. The problem is that sometimes I want an element to be opaque (for example text elements should not have background color, I want other elements to have that feature). Thus if I set the front div to opaque which have the text I will see the sliding lines gif itself. Is there a way to overpass the background div's background image on that area where the front div is visible and I could see everything BEHIND the back div?

Comment: I think you are using "opaque" when you mean "transparent" - opaque means you **can't** see through it, transparent means you **can**. (Technically, "translucent" is the correct term for "partially transparent/partially opaque", but that's not used very often.)

Comment: help those who want to help you by providing code from your application..